# How to differentiate Endpoint, Path, Parameter in url?

Tags: api

Can anyone explain me what is Endpoint, Path, Parameter in url with an example? Specially I can't identify Path. How to differentiate endpoint and path? We know that parameters start with "?". What is the Path's case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A typical GET request has these parts "http/https" AKA protocol ://something.com AKA host/path/path1?reqParam=xyz

You might want to read about URI, URLs to understand these more,

Comment: Host and Endpoint is same?